# variable is lost when calling it through slidify

Tags: r, slidify

After many slides working well, I am on a new one trying to execute a simple code:

````
   ```{r}
   summary(name_variable)
   ```
````

when running in the slide it gives the rigth answer. Nevertheless when executing Knit   it returns the message "object 'name_variable' not found". How is this possible?!
I have previously ran many slides that work fine.
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to create `name_variable` inside the `.Rmd` document. Possibly this single slide works, because you have `name_variable` stored in your `.GlobalEnv.`.

Comment: Hi ottlngr, thank you for your suggestion. All my variables come from an r file with its working directory. They run well both executing the r file or executing the call inside the slidify r code window. The problem arises when I run Knit: it does not find the object- varible ! And this is the only case, the other calls run well. The `.Rmd` document has been created inside the r file  working directory. This is driving me crazy!

Comment: Please sketch your folder and file structure.